# shape recognition with Javascript/HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, image-processing, shape-recognition

For a little project it would be nice if I have the possibility to make some shape recognition. It is a Webpage which shows a Visio Diagram. It shall be possible to click on one  of the shapes (only rectangles) and then additional Information shall be shown. To areas of a picture clickable is pretty easy in HTML. But unfortunately there are tons of several diagrams with tons of several shapes. The only method I know to make areas in a picture clickable is with fix pixels. Unfortunately the Visio diagrams change pretty often and so I would need to update the pixels often. Maybe you know any possibility with the known web-languages to recognize the shapes and set the areas in a dynamic way?

So long,
Stefan

Comment: Show us what you have tried,post some code preferably on a Fiddle?

Comment: All I have are the clickable areas in the pictures (just with <map> and <area>) I did some research, but found nothing in the web about the possibility to recognize shapes directly with JavaScript (for Instance). So I wanted to ask if anybody knows if this possibility actually exists). If not, an external Java program maybe could do the task...

Comment: Is Visio diagram inserted to HTML as picture (jpg, bmp, etc) and you want to analyse the source Visio file, or is it some OLE/ActiveX/... control?

Comment: It's just the Visio Diagram as an GIF where I made areas clickable

Comment: Using shape recognition might not help if there are "tons of shapes". How will you distinguish one shape from another?

Comment: they are "lined up". So there would be a "first" and a "second"...

And the Additional Information must then be lined up in the same order...